# what exactly the internal operation happening in this?

Tags: c#

what exactly the internal operation happening in this following code

```
public string s= "vinaysagarreddy";
public int n=1234;

public void  RString()
{
     string rs="vinaysagaarreddy";
     for(int i=s.Length-1;i>=0;i--)
         rs[i]=rs[i]+s[i];
}
```

where ad `rs=rs+s[i]` is working but

`rs[i]=rs[i]+s[i];` saying we cannot implicitly convert int to string as they are treated here as character array.

I need internal operation of this both statements

```
rs=rs+s[i]
rs[i]=rs[i]+s[i];
```

Comment: what do you mean by internal operation?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: that code doesn't compile because strings are immutable

Comment: i am performing string reverse operation.so i tried this rs[i]=rs[i]+s[i];

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to change `String` which is **immutable** another issue is that `Char + Char == int` and so **cast** is required:

```
public void RString() {
  string rs = "vinaysagaarreddy";

  // <- Error! rs is a string and so immutable; "rs[i] =" is not allowed
  for(int i = s.Length - 1;i >= 0; i--)
    rs[i] = rs[i] + s[i]; // Char + Char == int; so "rs[i] + s[i]" is int
  ...
```

Use `StringBuilder` to create/change a string

```
public void RString() {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("vinaysagaarreddy");

  // sb is a StringBuilder : OK to change
  for(int i = s.Length - 1;i >= 0; i--) 
    sb[i] = (Char) (sb[i] + s[i]); // <- Char + Char == int; cast required

  String rs = sb.ToString();

  ...
```

P.S. Please, format out your code - it's very difficult to read it